# CudNN Invalid input shape

Tags: python, numpy, keras, cudnn

I am inputing a 1 dimension numpy array into a CuDNNLSTM layer that is 19 integers long. So i set the input shape to input_shape=(19,) however when trying to train the model it is giving me the following error. I can see it is expecting a numpy array with a 3rd dimenstion but not sure why

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer cu_dnnlstm is incompatible with the layer: 
expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 19]
```

The full code of my model can be seen here, tho the issue is in the first input layer

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(HIDDEN_SIZE, input_shape=(19,)))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT_VALUE))
for _ in range(HIDDEN_LAYERS):
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT_VALUE))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='softmax')))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics= 
['mse'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCH_COUNT, validation_data=(x_test, 
y_test))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a sequence with 19 integers, then the timesteps dimension should be 19, and the features dimension should be 1, meaning the input shape to your network should be `(19, 1)`.

You should also reshape your data to match the new input shape.